# ASP.NET core 5 with react.js how remove routes from starter template?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

In the  JS templates that are created there is only SPA format for applications. But what if I don't need `Routes` and `SPA`? I need regular `MVC` with react components like slider, dropdowns etc. You can create a pure MVC project and manually add `React components`, but then it is not clear how to set up a server to debug react components. The approach to templates is very strange, there are only `SPA` projects but no other options. How can I remove react routes from the template that is being created?

Comment: Which template did you use to create React Project?

Comment: ASP.NET Core 5.0 with React.js (without Redux support)

Comment: I tried setting up a new ASP.NET Core React.js project as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli). And yes, it uses react router for routing but if you want to remove it, I don't see any challenge. You can remove the routing and just return a component like `return <Home/>` in `App.js`. Or maybe, I could not understand your question.

Comment: Do you want to remove routes from frontend and do routing at backend? So, are you looking for Server Side Rendering (SSR)?

Comment: I need a standard MVC project in which I could add a React component, for example, a button created in React, when you click on it, it writes "Hello world"

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/66739681/2873538 answer your question?